# error in while running a python script with OOP

Tags: python, oop, command-line

I have a binary file named "`infile.bin`". I want to make a program and change the infile a bit (input file with the value of each byte incremented by one) and then make `outfile`.
to do so I have made the following script in python:

```
import sys

class assignment():

    def __init__(self, infile, outfile):
        if not infile.endswith('.bin'):
            raise NameError("file should have '.bin' extension")
        self.infile = infile
        self.outfile = outfile

    def read_infile(self):
        with open(self.infile, "rb") as bin_in_file:
            data = bin_in_file.read()
        return data

    def increment_write(self):
        with open(self.outfile, "wb") as bin_out_file:
            bin_out_file.write(bytes(item + 1 for item in data))


infile = sys.argv[1]
outfile = sys.argv[2]
main = assignment(infile, outfile).read_infile()
main2 = assignment(infile, outfile).increment_write()

print main
print main2
```

to run it using this simple command

```
python program.py infile.bin out.bin
```

but when I run the script it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 24, in <module>
    main2 = assignment(infile, outfile).increment_write()
  File "program.py", line 18, in increment_write
    bin_out_file.write(bytes(item + 1 for item in data))
NameError: global name 'data' is not defined
```

and there is no "`out.bin`" do you know how to fix it?

Comment: ...pass the two parameters you defined in the `__init__` method when you instantiate the class?

Comment: You've defined your constructor to take two arguments, but you've passed none. You need to provide it arguments. Note, the error message may be confusing because it says your constructor takes three arguments but you've only passed one, but you must understand that the first argument, `self` is passed automatically for you. Note, you aren't doing anything with the argument you pass to your script, you are in charge of parsing those arguments.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have done (like eddied question) but got the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. What have you done *exactly*? You can edit your question with additional attempts and their error message

Comment: Oh, I see what you added, **but that's not what I'm talking about**. Again, you've defined your *constructor* i.e. `__init__` yo take two arguments, but you passed zero arguments. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: how can I fix the code? because I did not get what exactly you meant

Answer (score 0):

This is like, in Java (or any other OOP language), calling the constructor of a class that requires arguments, without any arguments. Of course, this won't work - but it's what you're doing when you do `assignment().read_infile()` - you create a new object of the class `assignment`, calling the constructor `__init__` with no arguments (besides `self`), and then calling `read_infile()` on the resulting object.

So you need to read the file from the command line and pass it to the constructor:

```
import sys
...
infile = sys.argv[1]  # refers to the second command-line argument, which would be "infile.bin"
outfile = "some_other_file.bin"
main = assignment(infile, outfile).read_infile()
```

Comment: I have edited the code like what you said but it return None

Comment: Well, look at how you implemented `read_infile()`. It's not returning anything. If you want it to, you need to put in a `return` statement somewhere.